# Football league winner vs cup winner

Tags: football, trivia

In England is FA Community Shield, in Italy Supercoppa, in Spain Supercopa, in Germany Supercup and so on

This title existe for every FIFA league or just only some league?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIFA doesn't impose any rule about what national competitions should be organized in each country.

By memory, I could think at least one place that doesn't has such game, although there's a league and a cup: Brazil.

Comment: Supercopa do Brasil has played only in 1990 and 1991, but I do not know the meaning